# Setting modules to false in webpack config breaks all css

Tags: webpack, sass, css-loader, css-modules, webpack.config.js

I have the following `webpack` config and everything works perfectly:

```
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        require('babel-plugin-transform-async-to-promises')
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [ "source-map-loader" ],
                enforce: "pre"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [ { loader:'style-loader'}, {loader : 'css-loader', options: {
                    modules: true,
                    sourceMap: IS_DEV,
                }}, {loader: 'sass-loader', options : {sourceMap: IS_DEV}} ]
            },
        ]
    },
```

However, when I try to set `modules` to `false`,

```
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [ { loader:'style-loader'}, {loader : 'css-loader', options: {
                    modules: false,
                    sourceMap: IS_DEV,
                }}, {loader: 'sass-loader', options : {sourceMap: IS_DEV}} ]
            },
```

all of my project's css stops working. How do I fix my CSS while having `modules` set to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing `modules:false` with

```
modules: {
    localIdentName: IS_DEV ? '[local]' : '[hash:base64:5]'
},
```

This makes it so that when running in dev mode (not production), the css classnames are visible and continue to work the same as in production. For more info, check out https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with how you apply css classes in components regarding whether Css-modules is enabled.
If you don't use CSS modules, you specify the literal CSS class names in components whereas when CSS modules is enabled, you turn to specify imported CSS class variables which are generated by webpack.
With the above being said, you probably want to change in accordance how you apply css classes in your component files.